# Hcitool returns input/output error after connecting to offline device

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, bluez, hci

I am using hci to connect to peripheral BLE devices. It works fine if all devices that I try to connect to are online.

However, as soon as I try to connect to device that is offline, or central somehow cannot connect to it, I get error saying:

```
Could not create connection: Connection timed out
```

After I get this timeout, any attempt to connect to device that is online fails with error saying:

```
Could not create connection: Input/output error
```

I can solve this by executing

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
```

but this is not helpful because I am using node.js library which uses hci, and I don't want to reset hci0 everytime error happens in application.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have tried this with bluez 5.37, 5.41 and 5.43 and get same results.

Is there a way I can solve this?

Comment: Have you tried cancel create connection  instead of hci reset ?  hcitool cmd 0x08 0x000E

Comment: @Preeti yes this works. But shouldn't hcitool cancel create connection by itself, when it gets connection timeout error?

Comment: I agree, the connection should be cancelled, either by hcitool or by the lower layer that knows there is a pending op.