# How to connect BLE devices using Linux bluetooth C library

Tags: c++, linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

1. **Description of the problem**

I am trying to connect my Bluetooth devices with BLE to a Linux system using the Bluetooth C libraries (I am programming using C++), so here is the code I am currently using:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>

#define CONNECT_TIMEOUT     60 /* sec */
#define BLE_ERROR(e) std::cout << "Error: " << e << ": " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;

void connect(std::string addr){
    uint16_t handle = 0;
    uint8_t initiator_filter = 0;
    uint8_t peer_type = LE_PUBLIC_ADDRESS;
    uint8_t own_type = LE_PUBLIC_ADDRESS;
    uint16_t interval = htobs(0x0005);
    uint16_t window = htobs(0x0005);

    uint16_t min_interval = 15;
    uint16_t max_interval = 15;

    uint16_t latency = 0;
    uint16_t timeout = 0;

    uint16_t min_ce_length = 1;
    uint16_t max_ce_length = 1;

    bdaddr_t bdaddr;

    int r, dev_id, dd = -1;

    dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
    if (dev_id < 0)
    {
        BLE_ERROR("No local device");
        goto finish;
    }
    dd = hci_open_dev(dev_id);
    if (dd < 0)
    {
        BLE_ERROR("Cannot open socket");
        goto finish;
    }

    r = str2ba(addr.c_str(), &bdaddr);
    if(r < 0){
        BLE_ERROR("Getting baddr");
        goto finish;
    }   

    r = hci_le_create_conn(dd,interval,window,initiator_filter,peer_type,
            bdaddr,own_type,min_interval,max_interval,latency,timeout,min_ce_length,max_ce_length,
            &handle,CONNECT_TIMEOUT * 1000000);
    if(r < 0){
        BLE_ERROR("Connecting device");
        goto finish;
    }

    printf("\tHandle: %d (0x%04x)\n", handle, handle);

finish:
    hci_close_dev(dd);
}

int main(){

    connect(""); //TODO Complete with a functional MAC Address

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE**: You need to set a specific MAC in `connect` function parameter. I am also compiling with g++ using the following command:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -g /home/maria/projects/TestStackOverBLE/main.cpp -o /home/maria/projects/TestStackOverBLE/main -lbluetooth
```

Here are more information about my hci0 device using `hciconfig -a` command:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 24:4B:FE:3A:1A:B6  ACL MTU: 1021:6  SCO MTU: 255:12
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:141559 acl:0 sco:0 events:5409 errors:0
    TX bytes:59986 acl:0 sco:0 commands:2084 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xfd 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'maria'
    Class: 0x3c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version:  (0xa)  Revision: 0x999
    LMP Version:  (0xa)  Subversion: 0x646b
    Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)
```

I am also using `Ubuntu 18.04` with:

`bluetoothctl v5.64`

`dbus v1.12.2-1ubuntu1`

`bluez v5.48-0ubuntu3`.

And the result I am getting when I run the application is the following:

```
Error: Connecting device: Input/output error
```

2. **Solution attempts**

I first tried to document myself about how the bluetooth C libraries for Linux works (itis difficult to find any documentation and less for BLE), I need to connect using BLE since my device does not allow communication using Bluetooth classic and I cannot find the reason for the problem I am having. I also have tried to restart both the bluetooth service (using `sudo service bluetooth restart`) and the hci0 device (using `sudo hciconfig hci0 reset`)  several times but none worked, I also tried restarting the PC and neither, I even tried the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994552/hcitool-returns-input-output-error-after-connecting-to-offline-device) that are quite similar to my case since previously the "Connection timeout" error has also happened to me but it didn't work either, it just returned the following code in case it was useful: Executing this command: `hcitool cmd 0x08 0x000E`I received the following output:

```
< HCI Command: ogf 0x08, ocf 0x000e, plen 0
> HCI Event: 0x0e plen 4
  02 0E 20 0C
```

What can I do about this problem?

**EDIT:** I was researching and found that making dbus calls to the bluetooth service using C/C++ could work for me but it is quite difficult to find good documentation or concrete connection examples despite having reviewed lots of github projects as most of the code is too convoluted, included in many files and/or consecutive calls for what I am trying to find/understand

Comment: My experience with a Raspberry Pi is that the C connect() method just doesn't work any more after the transition to dbus. You are right, there is no documentation for C, even if you use dbus functions, which would be the recommendation on a Pi. I wrote a C interface for the Pi which may or may not help, but for what it's worth, it's here https://github.com/petzval/btferret

Comment: @petzval Thanks, at least it is a very useful start, I have been looking over your code and the main problem I see is that the MAC must be specified in a txt that will then be read to obtain said data, in the end everything is summarized in a call to `read` to the socket of the hci device with the data corresponding to connecting action but, isn't there an easier way to do it specifying how to obtain said parameters given a MAC or at least where could you obtain the documentation to know which bytes need to be send to the hci so it can connect using BLE to a specific device given its MAC?

Comment: If you want to program via hci commands, see section 5.3.9 in the btferret documentation which details how to construct the packets. It has references to the relevant sections in the Bluetooth specification: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification-5-3/

Comment: If you are up for using the DBus APIs of Bluez, you might want to have a look at this C library I wrote. It intends to hide all DBus stuff and provide a simple C interface: https://github.com/weliem/bluez_inc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the old hci_xxx bluetooth C functions are doing at the lowest level. They probably don't work now because bluez/dbus is getting in the way. The following code works on a Raspberry Pi because it disables bluez first, and could be the basis of a C program - but it would be much easier to use one of the github libraries mentioned in the comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

struct sockaddr_hci
  {
  unsigned short hci_family;
  unsigned short hci_dev;      
  unsigned short hci_channel;
  };

  
struct hci_filter
  {
  unsigned long type_mask;
  unsigned long event_mask[2];
  unsigned short opcode;
  };

#define BTPROTO_HCI 1
#define SOL_HCI 0
#define HCI_FILTER 2
#define HCIDEVDOWN 0x400448CA

unsigned char eventmask[16] =  { 1,1,0x0C,8,0xFF,0xFF,0xFB,0xFF,0x07,0xF8,0xBF,0x3D }; 
unsigned char lemask[16] = { 0x01,0x01,0x20,0x08,0xBF,0x05,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
unsigned char leopen[30] = {1,0x0D,0x20,0x19,0x60,0,0x60,0,0,0,0x66,0x55,0x44,0x33,0x22,0x11,0,0x18,0,0x28,0,0,0,0x11,0x01,0,0,0,0}; 


int main()
  {
  int n,len,dd;
  struct sockaddr_hci sa;
  struct hci_filter flt;
  char buf[256];
  
  // set board address 00:1E:C0:2D:17:7C
  leopen[15] = 0x00;
  leopen[14] = 0x1E;
  leopen[13] = 0xC0;
  leopen[12] = 0x2D;
  leopen[11] = 0x17;
  leopen[10] = 0x7C;
  
  dd = socket(31, SOCK_RAW | SOCK_CLOEXEC | SOCK_NONBLOCK, BTPROTO_HCI);

  if(dd < 0)
    {
    printf("Socket open error\n");
    return(0);
    }
        
  ioctl(dd,HCIDEVDOWN,0);  // hci0
  close(dd); 
 
     
   // AF_BLUETOOTH=31
  dd = socket(31, SOCK_RAW | SOCK_CLOEXEC | SOCK_NONBLOCK, BTPROTO_HCI);

  if(dd < 0)
    {
    printf("Socket open error\n");
    return(0);
    }


  sa.hci_family = 31;   // AF_BLUETOOTH;
  sa.hci_dev = 0;       // hci0/1/2...
  sa.hci_channel = 1;   // HCI_CHANNEL_USER    
  
  if(bind(dd,(struct sockaddr *)&sa,sizeof(sa)) < 0)
    {
    printf("Bind failed\n");
    close(dd);
    return(0);
    }



  write(dd,eventmask,12);
  write(dd,lemask,12);  

  printf("Send hci LE connect\n"); 
  write(dd,leopen,29);
  
  printf("If get reply = 04 3E 13 01 00.. then has connected OK\n");  
  printf("REPLY =");
  for(n = 0 ; n < 10 ; ++ n)
    {
    len = read(dd,buf,sizeof(buf));
    for(n = 0 ; n < len ; ++n)
      printf(" %02X",buf[n]);
    printf("\n");
    sleep(1);
    }
  printf("\nExit and disconnect\n");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was also looking at your wiki on `btferret` github now knowing the problem with bluez and I found it quite interesting, I will probably try to see if I get any results following your documentation, additionally I have tried the example you have provided and I have obtained the following result:

`Send hci LE connect
If get reply = 04 3E 13 01 00.. then has connected OK
REPLY =
 04 0F 04 00 02 0D 20
 02 10 20 07 00 03 00 04 00 02 FFFFFFF7 00

Exit and disconnect` 
Do you know which could be the problem? or what could happened?

Comment: The first packet 04 0F 04 00 02 0D 20 is expected. The second packet 02 10... is an MTU request from the LE device (Bluetooth spec Vol 3 Part F 3.4.2.1) that you must reply to,

Comment: Thanks again, as I see in the bluetooth documentation it would be necessary to inform the client with the maximum MTU size, so I suppose that until this is done the handle will not be received, is there any point in the documentation that you provide in btferret which can help guide me in building a package for it? furthermore, in point 5.3.9 of your documentation you send packets to a feature with a 2-byte handle, I only know its 16-byte UUID, I was consulting other points like 4.2.15 or 5.1 but I don't see a clear way to do it , or is there a way to do a write with a 16 byte handle?

Comment: The LE device has connected but the 04 3E 13 connection complete event with the handle has not got though to read(). This may be something to do with the HCI_FILTER set up blocking those events - otherwise a mystery. However, the MTU request contains the handle as the second two bytes 10 20 (lo first). The handle is the low 12 bits = 0010, so put 10 00 in the reply as the handle.

Comment: To see the connection complete event, check that the event masks are set. See Vol 4 Part E 7.3.1 set bit 61 to enable LE meta events, and 7.8.1 set bit 0 to enable connection complete.

Comment: I changed the code listing to set the event masks directly rather than via ioctl.

Comment: It is quite useful for me when establishing communication, but seeing that a 2-byte handle is required for each characteristic, it can be a problem since I only know the UUID (16 bytes) that identifies some features where I write and read the data, these characteristics are specific to the BLE device so I don't think they appear in any associated list by default. In the implementation of btferret it is necessary to write them from a txt file, but is there any more organic way so that the 2-byte handles can be obtained directly from the code through a specific message?

Comment: As I saw in the `btferret` code `register_serial` is used to register a 16-byte UUID, but my features already exist in the device. Would it be possible to know the exact bytes (message) to send so it will be possible to receive the 2-byte handle with which to be able to operate with the characteristics to read and write on them? I don't find much information about this procedure in the documentation and that would help me a lot for finishing the code, many thanks.

Comment: See section 5.3.10 in the btferret documentation, which shows how to read the LE device's services. This returns the characteristic UUIDs and associated handles. The find_ctics() function in the library does this so it is an alternative to putting the handles in the txt file. Or see Vol 3 Part F 3.4.4.1 for a command that returns the characteristic given the UUID.

Comment: Thanks again, I have tried first to send my mtu size setting the same value as the received one (F7 and 0 are received as seen in the first comment) so the message I send is: `02 10 00 07 00 03 00 04 00 03 F7 00` , where byte [0] is the sending code, byte [1,2] is the handle, byte [3,4] is the number of bytes from the byte[5], byte[5,6] the number of bytes from byte[9],
byte[7,8] the LE code, byte [9] the Opcode 0x03 that appears in Vol3 Part F 3.4.2.2, and the last two bytes the same received MTU size, the result obtained is: `04 13 05 01 10 00 01 00 | 04 05 04 00 10 00 13`, why isn't 04 3E?

Comment: The second packet says that the remote device has initiated a disconnection. An easy way to find the characteristic handles is to use bluetoothctl. Start bluetoothctl, then: connect 00:1E:C0:2D:17:7C. It will then display all the characteristics as follows: /org/bluez/......./char000d. The handle is 000D.

Comment: Okay thanks! And do you know what could means the first package I received?

Comment: It's just a housekeeping message saying that one packet has been sent to handle 10 00, and can be ignored.