# Why does connect() fail with "no route to host" for Bluetooth sockets on Linux?

Tags: c, sockets, bluetooth, bluez, rfcomm

I am learning how to implement Bluetooth communication between two programs in C, for the Linux operating system, using low level socket programming via the basic socket API.

I already have good experience developing servers and clients using sockets in C, as well as Python, and I am fascinated by the similarity with which you can do Bluetooth socket communication as well.

Now, let me give you the reason why I am asking this question. Please forgive me, if anything sounds naive, because I am totally new to Bluetooth programming using sockets.

I understand RFCOMM as well as L2CAP protocols on a very high level. I am trying to develop a very basic server and client application that uses Bluetooth for communication.

I'm following the code from this resource:

https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html

The server is working fine and the `accept()` call blocks waiting for a new connection to arrive.

Now, things go broke, when I run the client application. I am using the MAC address of my Bluetooth adapter, which I found via running `hciconfig -a`, as the server's address to connect to. I only have one Bluetooth adapter.

But unfortunately, the `connect()` system call fails with an error code of 113, or `no route to host`!

I am totally frustrated & depressed because of this. It seems as if my Bluetooth learning journey has come to a stop! :(

Please do consider my situation and help me in every way possible!

I tried doing the same thing in Python using PyBlueZ, and I get the same error on the client side.

Why is this happening? What does `no route to host` even mean?

Please understand that I checked my Bluetooth connection, and it has no problems. I can transfer files from Ubuntu to my Android phone, etc.

Please note, that I am using VirtualBox to run Ubuntu on my Windows PC that has built-in Bluetooth support. But whenever Ubuntu uses Bluetooth, Windows seems to magically lose the Bluetooth option itself! I don't know why!

Comment: That MIT code stopped working a long time ago. See the code listings and reference section 5.3 in the documentation here: https://github.com/petzval/btferret. Bluez has to be stopped to make it work, and there is another code example (for an LE connection) in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72451087/how-to-connect-ble-devices-using-linux-bluetooth-c-library

Comment: @petzval Thankyou very much for the reply   If bluez is stopped the MIT code will work? How can I stop bluez then :)

Comment: @petzval How can the MIT code be modified, like what all additional functions to be added to make the MIT code work:)

Comment: @petzval Can you please guide me, in this because there is very little documentation on the internet. Also is localhost like communication possible with two programs using the same bluetooth adapter?

Comment: The Python version of the same code (btferret documentation 5.5.4) works because there is a layer of Dbus code hidden in Python. To make C code work you have to write the Dbus part yourself, use a library that includes Dbus, or avoid bluez/Dbus by getting an HCI socket directly to the adapter as in the btferret references, or try btferret which was written for a Raspberry Pi but should work on Ubuntu. The officially recommended and best method is to use Dbus, but it is hard to find documentation for C.